# Button event in Display Action Sheet

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I created display action sheet in Xamarin forms with the following code ,

*DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, "Email", "Twitter", "Facebook");*

Is it possible to set button event for Email,Twitter,Facebook?

Comment: At last i set event for email,twitter,facebook in that display action sheet

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DisplayAction returns Task<string>, in order not to block the main thread. To handle selection you need to use it in a way similar to this:

```
            var action = await DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, "Email", "Twitter", "Facebook");
            switch (action){
            case "Email": 
                DoSomething(); 
                break;
            case "Twitter": 
                DoSomethingElse(); 
                break;
                ...                 
            }
```